# How to visualize charts in Visual Studio and Azure ML through R script?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, rtvs

I have seen on various examples (even in Azure ML) that you are able to create appealing charts using R in Visual Studio (not R Studio!), but I have no clue how they did it. I am experienced with R, but if someone could point me in the right direction of how to visualize data sets in Visual Studio and Azure ML; I would really appreciate it.
Here is an example I would like to duplicate (in both Azure ML and Visual Studio): [Visual studio chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aoGB.jpg)

Image source: https://regmedia.co.uk/2016/03/09/r_vis_studio_plot.jpg?x=648&y=348&crop=1

Comment: You need [R Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/rtvs-vs). Also read the [Documentation](http://microsoft.github.io/RTVS-docs/).

Comment: Go through this: [RTVS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/understanding-the-visual-studio-ide-for-r-language/)... might find this useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install ggplot2 in your solution in the Visual Studio extension Open R (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/rtvs-vs.aspx) through this line of code and visualize it within the R Plot window in Visual Studio after creating your R-project:

```
install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
```

The reason I have «library(ggplot2)» is to check if the package got successfully installed, else you would get an error like this: **Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’**

So if you don’t get that error; you should be good to go.

For your question about how to output charts; you simply have to populate the ggplot2 charts from a datasource, like in my example below (csv-file):

```
dataset1 <- read.csv("Adult Census Income Binary Classification dataset.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")

head(dataset1)

install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

names(dataset1) <- sub(pattern = ',', replacement = '.', x = names(dataset1))

foo = qplot(age, data = dataset1, geom = "histogram", fill = income, position = "dodge");

print(foo)

bar = qplot(age, data = dataset1, geom = "density", alpha = 1, fill = income);

print(bar)
```

Here you can see that I create two charts, one histogram and one density-chart.

[image]

In Azure ML, the same charts (this time I included a histogram for Relationships as well), would look like this:

```
// Map 1-based optional input ports to variables

dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame

library(ggplot2)

library(data.table)

names(dataset1) <- sub(pattern=',', replacement='.', x=names(dataset1))

// This time we need to specify the X to be sex; which we didn’t need in Visual Studio

foo = qplot(x=sex, data=dataset1, geom="histogram", fill=income, position="dodge");

print(foo)

foo = qplot(x=relationship, data=dataset1, geom="histogram", fill=income, position="dodge");

print(foo)

foo = qplot(x=age, data=dataset1, geom="density", alpha=0.5, fill=income);

print(foo)

// Select data.frame to be sent to the output Dataset port maml.mapOutputPort("dataset1");
```

Remember to put all of this in a “Execute R Script module” in order to run it correctly. After that, you can right lick the module and visualize the result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referring to the R Tools for Visual Studio.  These provide a means to develop and debug R code in the Visual Studio IDE, and can produce plots like the one you shared.

However, that plot looks like a pretty standard chart from the CRAN ggplot2 package, which means it could have been just as easily produced from R code running in the R console or RStudio.

This posting on the R-bloggers site should help get you started with ggplot2.

http://www.r-bloggers.com/basic-introduction-to-ggplot2/

Good luck, and enjoy!
jmp